# Program Counter not incrementing

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am attempting to create a program counter for a RISC processor, but I am unsure why the test bench isn't working as expected. There might be something wrong with the way the test bench is written, but I can't seem to find it. In the simulation of the test bench, the counter value doesn't seem to increment by one as expected. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
module ProgramCounter 

// identify inputs and outputs, define if the input/output is signed. 
(
input Clock,
input logic Reset,
input logic [15:0] LoadValue,
input logic LoadEnable,
input logic signed [8:0] Offset,
input logic OffsetEnable,
output logic signed [15:0] CounterValue
);

// Clock, Reset, LoadEnable and OffsetEnable triggered at positive edge of clock.
    always_ff@(posedge Clock)
    begin
        if (Reset) CounterValue <= '0; //if reset is TRUE, CounterValue is zero.
        else if (LoadEnable) CounterValue <= LoadValue; //if LoadEnable is TRUE, CounterValue is equal to LoadValue.
        else if (OffsetEnable) CounterValue <= CounterValue + Offset;//if OffsetEnableEnable is TRUE, CounterValue is CounterValue plus Offset.
        else CounterValue <= CounterValue + 1;//otherwise, CounterValue increases with the clock.
    end


endmodule

// ProgramCounterTestBench
//
//
// This module implements a testbench for 
// the Program Counter 
//

module ProgramCounterTestBench();

    // These are the signals that connect to 
    // the program counter
    logic               Clock = '0;
    logic               Reset;
    logic signed       [15:0]   LoadValue;
    logic               LoadEnable;
    logic signed  [8:0] Offset;
    logic                   OffsetEnable;
    logic signed  [15:0]    CounterValue;

    // this is another method to create an instantiation
    // of the program counter
    ProgramCounter uut
    (
        .Clock,
        .Reset,
        .LoadValue,
        .LoadEnable,
        .Offset,
        .OffsetEnable,
        .CounterValue
    );
    

    default clocking @(posedge Clock);
    endclocking
        
    always  #10  Clock++;

    initial
    begin
        Reset = 0;
        LoadEnable = 0;
        OffsetEnable = 0;
        LoadValue = 16'b0000000000000000;
        Offset = 9'b000000000;
        CounterValue = 16'b0000000000000010;

        #60

        #10     Reset = 0;
                LoadEnable = 1;
                LoadValue = 16'b0101010101010101;

        #10     Reset = 1;
                LoadEnable = 0;
                OffsetEnable = 0;
                LoadValue = 16'b0101010101010101;
                Offset = 9'b000000000;

        #10     Reset = 0;
                LoadEnable = 1;
                OffsetEnable = 0;
                LoadValue = 16'b0101010101010101;
                Offset = 9'b000000000;  

        #10     Reset = 0;
                LoadEnable = 0;
                OffsetEnable = 0;
                                        

        #10     Reset = 0;
                LoadEnable = 0;
                OffsetEnable = 1;
                LoadValue = 16'b0101010101010101;
                Offset = 9'b101000000;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I get compile errors with multiple simulators.  For example, the Cadence simulator generates this error:

```
        .CounterValue
                    |
xmelab: *E,ICDPAV : Illegal combination of driver and procedural assignment to variable CounterValue detected (procedural assignment found in initial block
```

You can try your code on multiple simulators on `edaplayground` when you sign up for a free account.

The problem is in the testbench with this line:

```
    CounterValue = 16'b0000000000000010;
```

The `CounterValue` signal in the testbench has multiple drivers:

1. The instance output port connection
2. The above line in the `initial` block

You should only allow the instance to drive this signal.  When you delete the line above, you will see the counter increment as expected.